# after typing finishes get value from dynamically created textbox

Tags: jquery

I have below dynamically created textbox, all I want to do is get the id and value on below textbox after user finishes typing.I use id attribute to get id first and go to next cell to the same row to make a calculation.I have below javascript but it is not working

```
 td><input type='text' class='perftextbox' id = 'Working_Days" + k + "'/></td>

$("[id^=Working_Days]").typing({
    start: function (event, $elem) {},
    stop: function (event, $elem) {
        var idname = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(idname);
    },
    delay: 10
});
```

Comment: `typing()` what is that? Are you including plugin? Any error in console? Etc...

Comment: I'm assuming the OP is using the typing plugin for jQuery: http://lab.narf.pl/jquery-typing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("[id^=Working_Days]").typing({
    start: function (event, $elem) {},
    stop: function (event, $elem) {
        var idname = $elem.attr('id'); 
        alert(idname);
    },
    delay: 10
});
```

Comment: I guess `$elem` is the relevant textbox

Comment: Is your problem because of dynamic elements or what? You should at least improve your question by referring to relevant plugin, just not only let us guessing what could be your issue. That's said, looks like plugin doesn't support delegation, so once new elements added, initialize plugin on it.

Comment: @A.Wolff ok if I would not use typing attribute how can I get id of a dynamically created textbox?

Comment: @user3416204 It's unclear what you are asking, still guessing... `$(document).on('keyup', "[id^=Working_Days]", function(){
    alert(this.id);
});`